# How to ensure consistency of data from webhook

Tags: rdbms

I am building a database where some tables will be populated in a "use it or lose it" scenario automated application flow. By this I mean the data will come in via a Webhook (PayPal IPN) and if my RDBMS rejects the INSERT then the data will be lost i.e. There is no operator to inspect/correct the data and retry.

A simple solution to this is to make the DB fields as simple as possible by exclude `NOT NULL` and even potentially making fields text based.

The problem of consistency still exists. How can I ensure this? Should I include the checks that would potentially be included in the database and log warnings if there is a problem.

Realistically, things will only break if the WebHook service changes but I want to be prepared for such a scenario.

UPDATE:

I guess another approach could be to cache all incoming webhook messages verbatim in a NoSQL store. Regardless of the above problem, that's probably a good idea.

Comment: Try using ``commit`` and ``rollback`` commands https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm

Comment: I think you are missing the problem. What would I do after I rollback??

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how important it is for you to not lose this event/data.

There is always the possibility that the webhook is never called, due to network issues or other problemes, but if we assume that PayPal is responsible for ensuring that the webhook on your server is called eventually (i.e. they have retries on their side if things fail), you can make a near 100% guarantee that you don't lose the data on your side, by doing one or more of the following:

- In the servlet/application receiveing the webhook on your side, make sure you do as little as possible with it, except possibly validating the data to ensure that it in a consistent form that can be stored on your side. It may be argued that you should also persist invalid events or events with unexpected data, in the case you want to re-play them at a later time.
- If you have a message broker/queue system or other high-availabilty distributed data store in place (such as RabbitMQ, Kafka, Cassandra, Redis, or similar), you should send the event there. You may chose to always do this, or only do this if wriiting directly to the database fails, but for simplicity, it might be better to always put the event on the queue and have a separate process that reads from the queue and writes the data to the SQL database.
- If you do not have a queue system, or if storing the event in the queue system fails, you can persist events on local disk¹ on the node processing the webhook. This a fall-back that may help you recover "lost" events in case writing to the database and/or queue system fails.
- In a separate process, fetch events from the queue or other distributed storage, and insert it into the database. This process should only acknoledge the message on the queue if writing to the databse succeeds, if not, the message should not be acknowleged, so the mesage can be re-processed.

There more of these techniques you implemnt, the closer you get to 100% guarantee of never missing an event. In the end, everything can fail, and if you want something that is really robust, you should design it to expect that anything and everything will fail at some point.

However, even if yuo have a distributed message queue, you can lose data if writing to the queue fails and writing to local disk fails at the same time. The only way to recover data in this scenario is to get PayPal to re-play the event and call your webhook again with the same data, or retrieve the same data manually from PalPal (if possible).

BTW: Whether to use a queue or just a "dumb" distributed data store for storing events depends on whether you care about processing order, processing the same event multiple times, etc.

¹ *If you log the data when processing it on the webhook node, you get local disk persistance "for free", but this depends on you being able to actually log all data in the event, which may not be possible if the event contains sensitive data. If you have some sort of log-shipping or distributed logging server in plcace, this may also (partially) protect you from the disk on the webhook node failling or the node itself failing (i.e. virtual/cloud server being restarted and losing its disk).*